# How to use $$FullList on Quantity data-type?

Tags: tally

I'm trying to extract values from Inventory entries under voucher object. I'm successfully able to extract stock item name which is String data-type like this:

`$$FullList:InventoryEntries:$StockItemName`

However, I'm trying to extract Billed Quantity which is actually a quantity data type as you can see here:

[image]

Since a quantity type I cannot use $$FullList on $BilledQty since it works only on String as you can see here:

[image]

Can someone help me how to get the full list of the billed qty from voucher?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could paste the complete code (TDL or otherwise). Also it is preferable if you can mention the errors you get.

This works as below:

```
[Collection: VchColl]
    Type: Voucher
    Compute: List :$$FullList:InventoryEntries:$StockItemName
    Compute: TotalQty: $$FullList:InventoryEntries:$BilledQty
```

After declaring the collection above, you can use $List and $TotalQty. 
Attaching a screenshot here:
[image: Output]